# Android camera and gallery

Tags: android, android-camera, android-gallery

I'm trying to load picture from gallerry and from camera, but when i choose picture from gallery or when I take picture from camera, my app just exit and I cannot figure out why. It also never calls onActivityResult() method. Here's the entire class, where, in doStartCamera() and pickFromGallery() methods, startActivityForResult() method is called (and should trigger camera and gallery result):

```
public class UserProfileCoverItem extends Fragment implements IDataFetch {
private static UserProfileCoverItem myFrag;
private View v;
//private Context context;
private eKeshGlobal global;

private ProgressBar bar;    
private Profile mProfile;   
private TextView tvUsername, tvLevel;   
private ImageView ivAvatar;
//private Bitmap mBitmap;

private String imagepath = null;
//private String mOriginalPhotoPath;
//private boolean pinCodeActive;
private File tempImageFile;

public static final int REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA = 21222;
public static final int REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY = 31333;

public static UserProfileCoverItem getInstance(Profile profile) {
    if (myFrag == null){
        myFrag = new UserProfileCoverItem();
    }
    myFrag = new UserProfileCoverItem();
    myFrag.mProfile = profile;
    return myFrag;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle 
savedInstanceState) {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_user_profile_cover, container, false);
    //context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    global = (eKeshGlobal) getActivity().getApplicationContext();
    //pinCodeActive = global.getPinCodeActive();

    ivAvatar = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivUserProfileAvatar);
    tvUsername = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvUserProfileUsername);
    tvLevel = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvUserProfilePoints);
    bar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.pbUserProfileCover);
    bar.setProgress((Integer) mProfile.getPoints());
    tvUsername.setText(mProfile.getFirstName() + " " + mProfile.getLastName());
    tvLevel.setText(mProfile.getLevelName());

    ivAvatar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            doCreateCameraDialog();
        }
    });


    v.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new 
ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            v.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            if (global.getAvatarBitmap() == null){
                new GetUserPhoto(UserProfileCoverItem.this, 
global).execute();
            } else {
                Utils.drawAvatar(global.getAvatarBitmap(), ivAvatar);
            }               
        }
    });
    return v;
}

private void doCreateCameraDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    CharSequence[] items = {getResources().getString(R.string.label_photo_camera), 
getResources().getString(R.string.label_photo_gallery)};
    adb.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface d, final int n) {
            d.dismiss();
            switch (n) {
            case 0:
                doStartCamera();
                break;
            case 1:
                pickFromGallery();
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    });

    adb.setNegativeButton((getResources().getString(R.string.label_cancel)), null);
    adb.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.label_photo_title));
    adb.show();     
}

private void doStartCamera() {
    tempImageFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), 
"eKeshUserTemp.jpg");
    try {
        tempImageFile.createNewFile();
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        //intent.putExtra("data", tempImageFile.getAbsolutePath());
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(tempImageFile));
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void pickFromGallery() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, 
getResources().getString(R.string.label_photo_gallery_select)), 
            REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY && resultCode != 0) {
         onGalleryResult(data);
     } else if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA && resultCode != 0) {
         onCameraResult(data);
     }
}

public void onGalleryResult(Intent data) {
    try {
        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        imagepath = getPath(selectedImageUri);

        new AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>() {
            private Bitmap result;

            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
                result = processImage(params[0]); 
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                if (result != null && !result.isRecycled()) {
                    Utils.drawAvatar(result, ivAvatar);
                    ((Main) getActivity()).menuFrag.getResultOk(bitmap);
                    new UploadUserPhoto(global, result).execute();
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
            };
        }.execute(imagepath);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e("onGalleryResult", e.toString());
    }
}

public void onCameraResult(Intent data) {
    new AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            return processImage(params[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (result != null && !result.isRecycled()) {
                Utils.drawAvatar(result, ivAvatar);
                ((Main) getActivity()).menuFrag.getResultOk(result);
                new UploadUserPhoto(global, result).execute();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        };
    }.execute(tempImageFile.getAbsolutePath());
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    //Cursor cursor = getActivity().managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String out = cursor.getString(column_index);
    cursor.close();
    return out;
}

private Bitmap processImage(String path){
    try {
        Bitmap mBitmap;
        File f = new File(path);
        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(f.getPath());
        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(
                ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,
                ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

        int angle = 0;
        if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90) {
            angle = 90;
        } else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180) {
            angle = 180;
        } else if (orientation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270) {
            angle = 270;
        }

        Matrix mat = new Matrix();
        mat.postRotate(angle);

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 2;
        options.inPurgeable = true;
        options.inInputShareable = true;
        mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, options);
        Log.i ("Slika", "w:" + mBitmap.getWidth() + " h:" + mBitmap.getHeight());
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0,
                mBitmap.getWidth(), mBitmap.getHeight(), mat, true);

        // save temp small image
        //mBitmap = Utils.createScaledBitmap(mBitmap, 480f, 
640f);//Utils.doscaleBitmap(mBitmap,600);
        //mBitmap = Utils.doscaleBitmap(mBitmap,500);

        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, bytes);
        Log.i ("Slika", "w:" + mBitmap.getWidth() + " h:" + mBitmap.getHeight());

        tempImageFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
"eKeshUserTemp.jpg");
        tempImageFile.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(tempImageFile);
        fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        fo.close();

        return mBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.w("TAG", "-- Error in setting image");
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError oom) {
        oom.printStackTrace();
        Log.w("TAG", "-- OOM Error in setting image");
    } catch (NullPointerException esd) {
        esd.printStackTrace();
        Log.w("TAG", "-- NullPointerException");
    } catch (RuntimeException ed) {
        ed.printStackTrace();
        Log.w("TAG", "-- RuntimeException");
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public void getResultOk(Object... params) {
    Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) params[0];

    Utils.drawAvatar(photo, ivAvatar);
    ((Main) getActivity()).menuFrag.getResultOk(photo);
}

@Override
public void getResultError(Object... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void getResultError() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

and here is onActivityResult() implemented in Main.java (the main activity):

```
    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (mContent!= null) {
            Log.d("class", mContent.getClass().toString());
            mContent.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
```

I know that some identical questions already exist, but they didnt help me to resolve this specific problem.

Comment: I understand that you found the problem. Please update the Q, or delete it.

Answer (score 2):

I looked at your code and it is similar to mine in the sense that I am using fragment to select image activity to handle communication and again update fragment. The only difference in my code was the way I am checking RESULT_OK. I used getActivity().RESULT_OK and am preety sure that should be done. If this doesnot work for you let me know.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d("activity result ", "reached");
    if (requestCode == 4) {
        Log.d("activity result ", "one");
        if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
            //set image view here
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Actually RESULT_OK is a static variable so you should access it in a static way, so it didn't worked... Error was in onCreate() method in main activity class, but thanks anyway...